# multiply the values of a ton of arrays then put it back in origianl form

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a chart that gets data from an API endpoint with open, close, high, and low data for a bar chart like the ones you see for stocks. I make the endpoint request, and use .map to reach for example the value for low.

The issue is that the result needs to be multiplied by 213 before being displayed on the chart, how can I write a code that takes the value of every single one of these arrays, multiplies the inner value by 213, and puts it back in the original form so the chart can use it?

code used to reach the data:
**UPDATE:**

```
const bars = response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({
            time: new Date(el.timeInterval.minute).getTime(),
            low: el.low,
            high:  el.high,
            open: Number(el.open),
            close: Number(el.close),
            volume: el.volume
        }))
```

As you can see this uses .map(el to find the data,

what I did was this for the low,high, open, close, and volume arrays

```
const usdhigh = response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({high: el.high}))
       const usdlow =response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({low: el.low}))
       const usdopen =  response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({open: (el.open)}))
       const usdclose =  response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({close: (el.close)}))
       const usdvolume =  response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({volume: (el.volume)}))
      
       console.log (usdhigh)
       const usdhiughbnb = usdhigh.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, high: item.high * 213};
    });
    
    const usdlowbnb = usdlow.map((item) => {
      return { ...item, low: item.low * 213};
  });
       
  console.log(usdhiughbnb)
       const usdopenbnb = usdopen.map((item) => {
        return { ...item, open: item.open * 213};
    });

    const usdclosebnb = usdclose.map((item) => {
      return { ...item, close: item.close * 213};
  });
  console.log (usdclosebnb)

  const usdvolumebnb =  usdvolume.map((item) => {
    return { ...item, volume: item.volume * 213};
});
```

For time which shouldn't be multiplied, I put this:

```
let timesf = response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({
  time: new Date(el.timeInterval.minute).getTime()   }))
```

and then rewrote the bars section like so:

```
const bars = (
            time = timesf,
            low = usdlowbnb,
            high = usdhiughbnb,
            open = Number(usdopenbnb),
            close = Number(usdclosebnb),
            volume = usdvolumebnb
        )
```

Unfortunatly this did not work, although the console.log for the values other then time all showed up correctly, this information did not get passed on correctly and the graph did not display.

I am not sure why this doesn't work, but is there a better way to integrate the multiplication into the values and keep const bars but just multiply some values in it?

```
const bars = response2.data.data.ethereum.dexTrades.map(el => ({
        time: new Date(el.timeInterval.minute).getTime(),
        low: el.low,
        high:  el.high,
        open: Number(el.open),
        close: Number(el.close),
        volume: el.volume
    }))
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: `const result = yourArray.map((v) => (v * 213));`

Comment: Just to understand you, right. Is it an array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's easy. If you have an array of objects, you can just use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to spread the rest of the object and multiply the values you'd like to change by 213:

```
let arr = [
    { key: 1, value: 10 },
    { key: 2, value: 103 },
    { key: 3, value: 45 },
    { key: 4, value: 89 },
];

arr = arr.map((item) => {
    return { ...item, value: item.value * 213 };
});

console.log(arr);

// expected output: [ { key: 1, value: 2130 }, { key: 2, value: 21939 }, { key: 3, value: 9585 }, { key: 4, value: 18957 } ]
```

Et voilà... values changed.